# Multiple Landing Pages Under Same Url

Tags: 7

I need some suggestions, I am not sure which direction to go to do this, but I need to do 4 different landing pages, with 4 different urls, example http://site.com/landingpage?blue=1, http://site.com/landingpage?blue=2.

Now everything is almost the same on the landing pages except for a banner thats going to be on the front and on 2 of the landing pages the layout will be different. I am using panels for the pages. Should I make 4 different panels for them or can panels allow me to change different elements on certain urls? How would I do that using panels? Or would you suggest a different module?

Any suggestions is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a way to do something like you are talking about is creating one panel page with panels variants and showing each one depending on selection rules.
[image: Creating variant]

[image: selection rules]
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [View Mode Page](https://drupal.org/project/view_mode_page) to achieve this. Just create a new view mode per page, which if you want the same display, just clone it for each view mode and apply the styling with CSS for each view mode.